# SQL Trigger - cant call function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, triggers

Getting ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification error for this trigger, can figure out why? Tables - TESTCOMM_FINDCOMM - 2 numbers, Price and Comm

```
create or replace trigger TESTCOMM_FINDCOMM
AFTER
insert or update on "TESTCOMM"
for each row
referencing new as new and old as old
begin
  :NEW.Commission:= :NEW.Price*get_Comm(:NEW.Price);      
end;
```

Function get_Comm

```
create or replace function get_Comm
(i_price in NUMBER)
return NUMBER
as
 o_COMMISSION_percent PRICECOMMISSION.COMMISSION%type;
begin
  select COMMISSION
into o_COMMISSION_percent
  from (
      select COMMISSION,
             rank () over (order by Price desc) rnk
        from PRICECOMMISSION
        where PRICE <= i_price
  ) where rnk = 1;      

  return o_COMMISSION_percent;

end;​
```

Comment: This looks like Oracle, is it? SQL is a language that is implemented by multiple RDBMS', which one are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger is an AFTER insert/update trigger - you can not modify :NEW values after the insert/update.

More info on AFTER triggers can be found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php). What you should be looking at is a [BEFORE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php) trigger.